# How should I bump my app version while still in initial developments using SemVer?

Tags: semantic-versioning

Following the [SemVer guidelines](https://semver.org/) with `x.y.z`, I know I should start my developments with version `0.1.0` and do the following in case of:

- Breaking change: increment **y** instead of **x** (which shall remain to `0` until the first production release).
- Feature: ???
- Patch: increment **z**.

As the question marks suggest, should I increment **y** or **z** when adding a new feature to my unreleased app?

Answer (score 0):

The [SemVer specification](https://semver.org/#semantic-versioning-specification-semver) gives these instructions:

> 1. Patch version Z (x.y.Z | x > 0) MUST be incremented if only backwards compatible bug fixes are introduced. [...]
> 2. Minor version Y (x.Y.z | x > 0) MUST be incremented if new, backwards compatible functionality is introduced to the public API. [...]
> 3. Major version X (X.y.z | X > 0) MUST be incremented if any backwards incompatible changes are introduced to the public API. [...]

So basically, Z is incremented for fixes, Y is incremented for features, X is incremented for breaking changes **whether they're about features or fixes**.

---

While in the initial developments phase, we just don't deal with the *breaking change* part because we have no production users. Therefore, we should increment Z for fixes, and Y for features,
**no matter if the changes are backwards compatible or not**.